# Confused with Helm dependency management

Tags: kubernetes-helm

In my parent chart Chart.yaml I have

```
dependencies:
  - name: postgresql11
    repository: "@myrepo"
    version: 8.9.7
    condition: postgresql11.enabled
  - name: postgresql12
    repository: "@myrepo"
    version: 8.9.7
    condition: postgresql12.enabled
```

In the same parent chart values.yaml I have:

```
postgresql11:
  enabled: true

postgresql12:
  enabled: false
```

My problem is that unless I run `helm dep update` neither subchart is downloaded and installed (I'm expecting the postgresql11 subchart to be installed). If I run `helm dep update` both subcharts are pulled, ignoring my ruleset which indicates that only postgresql11 should be installed.

Can anybody shed some light on what I'm doing wrong here, and what the relationship is between helm dependency build/update and the conditional rules in Chart.yaml? I'm also curious why there is an `enabled` field in Chart.yaml which seems redundant with the `condition` field? I'm running Helm 3.2.4.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

**Helm Dependency Update:**

Update the on-disk dependencies to mirror Chart.yaml.

This command verifies that the required charts, as expressed in 'Chart.yaml', are present in 'charts/' and are at an acceptable version. It will pull down the latest charts that satisfy the dependencies, and clean up old dependencies.

On successful update, this will generate a lock file that can be used to rebuild the dependencies to an exact version.

**Helm Dependency Build:**

Build out the charts/ directory from the Chart.lock file.

Build is used to reconstruct a chart's dependencies to the state specified in the lock file. This will not re-negotiate dependencies, as 'helm dependency update' does.

If no lock file is found, 'helm dependency build' will mirror the behavior of 'helm dependency update'.

Answer (score 2):

The command `helm dep update` does not use `values.yaml` and that is why your dependencies are updated even if you have them disabled in `values.yaml`.

To understand the `enabled` for dependencies, read the section "Tags and Condition fields in dependencies" in the [Helm: Charts](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/) documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I've come across that page. Thanks for your explanation pertaining to helm dep update. How do I do what I want  to do then in having conditional dependencies? What am I doing wrong, above? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`helm dependency update` command will download all the subchart specified in the `dependencies` option and download it to the charts/ directory, even you have them disabled in values.yaml. However, only enabled charts will be installed.

To release the new changes/version you need to run the command `helm upgrade <chart-name> <chart-dir-location>`.
Please refer https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/

Comment: Thanks mebinspace for clarifying this!

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong then, and why my helm upgrade commands with the provided values are being ignored, as I've described? I'm unable to find the right way to install only the charts I want by setting values.

Comment: I tried the same scenario and I'm able to install my desired subchart without any issues.  I'm using Helm - v3.2.4, K8s- v1.17.0. please share more details including your chart manifest?